# How to set transparency and background colour for a pie chart matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm sure this is somewhere in `SO` but I can't see to find it anywhere. I'm trying to alter the `colour` `transparency` or `alpha` for a `pie chart` in `matplotlib`. I'm also hoping to set the background `colour` to `grey`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = ({ 
    'C' : ['X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z','A','X','Y','Z'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,12))
ax.grid(False)
plt.style.use('ggplot')

df['C'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'pie')

plt.show
```

I cant seem to change the `pie chart` `colour` `transparency` or use the background generally created by `'ggplot'`?

Comment: To set background color to grey you can use `fig.patch.set_facecolor('grey')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two similar ways: the basic idea is to define the wedge properties
using `wedgeprops`. On a side note, I would rather use `lightgrey` background as it looks much better than `grey` which is a bit dark.

**First**:

```
df['C'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'pie',wedgeprops={'alpha':0.5})
fig.set_facecolor('lightgrey')
```

[image]

**Second**: using `plt.pie`

```
plt.pie(df['C'].value_counts(), wedgeprops={'alpha':0.5})
fig.set_facecolor('lightgrey')
```

[image]